# Upper Bound for indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, special-functions

For a given $t \in \mathbb{R}$, I want to know if there is a tighter bound on the function $u(x) =\mathbb{1}_{(x \geq t)}$ than $\bar{u}(s,x) = e^{2s(x-t)}$, $s > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly $\min(\bar u(s_1,x),\bar u(s_2,x),\ldots,\bar u(s_n,x))$, for a selection of positive numbers $s_1,\ldots,s_n$, will give a tighter bound than any one of them by itself.  It might be helpful for us  to know what your goal is.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve involves an integral $\int{\mathbb{1}_{(x \geq t)} f(x) dx}$ and I'm trying to find an upper bound for this integral. The function $f$ here is general. By introducing the function $\bar{u}(s,x)$, we can obtain a bound by minimizing over $s$. I was thinking is it possible to do better?

Comment: I'd compute $\int \bar u(s,x)f(x)\,dx$ and then minimize the resulting funtion of $s$.  Does it have a nice expression?

Comment: Applying Jensen's inequality, I can manage to get the expression of the integral as function of $s$ and thus the minimization problem is simple.